# Conversion of generic types

Tags: c#, .net

I have below class structure:

```
public class FirstContextController : AFirstContextController

public abstract class AFirstContextController : ABaseController<AFirstContextView>

public abstract class ABaseController<TView> where TView : ABaseView

public abstract class AFirstContextView : ABaseContextView

public abstract class ABaseContextView : ABaseView

public abstract class ABaseView : UserControl
```

Now I create an instance of my controller:

```
AFirstContextController firstContextController = new FirstContextController();
```

and need to return it from the method:

```
public static ABaseController<ABaseContextView> GetContextController( ... )
{
    return firstContextController;
}
```

But then I get an error:

Cannot implicitly convert type '**AFirstContextController**' to '**ABaseController**'

So I tryied many casting (for example):

```
return (ABaseController<AFirstContextView>)firstContextController;

return (ABaseController<ABaseContextView>)( (ABaseController<AFirstContextView>)firstContextController );
```

But still get similar errors according to conversion.
So what conversion should I apply to return it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an interface derived from `ABaseController<ABaseContextView>` to make it work.

This has to do with variance and covariance. Reed more about it on [MSDN: Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You will have to mark the `ABaseContextView` with `out` in your interface definition, so the signature should be something like `IBaseController<out ABaseContextView>`.

Example:

```
public abstract class ABaseController<TView> : IBaseController<TView> where TView : ABaseView
{
    public void SomeMethod() { }
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface IBaseController<out TView> where TView : ABaseView
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
```

Then your current method should read:

```
public static IBaseController<ABaseContextView> GetContextController( ... )
{
    return firstContextController;
}
```

Comment: Have I understanded you correctly - do I have to change my method definition from: public static ABaseController<ABaseContextView> GetContextController( ... ) to public static ABaseController<**out** ABaseContextView> GetContextController( ... ) ? I have done it so, but now get an error: **Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant.**

Comment: Partially yes, you have to make an interface too, since classes can't be covariant.

Comment: But that is the problem that I can not change my abstract class to interface because it derives from UserControll. So is there another way to achieve my goal - have a generic or 'generic like' method that can return a controllers from above structure?

Comment: You shouldn't change your abstract class to an interface, you should add an interface definition to it in order to make this work.

Comment: Thank you Patrik for your explanation, but how can interface derive from class? You have written: **You need an interface derived from ABaseController<ABaseContextView> to make it work.** but ABaseController is class. Could you please share me more detailed code snippet to solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to create an interface with the same signature as your class, and you include all properties and methods you want to use from your class. Then you let the class implement that interface.

Comment: @user3057544: Added a sample from the top of my head.